# Creating an NPM package from existing module and its dependencies

Tags: angular, npm, angular6

I'm in the process of converting module in angular to an NPM packages.
I've gone through the process of **ng generate library name --prefix=**.

Built it out and compiled to a dist folder.

The existing component uses dependencies from other components/services in the app folder. I have some in a "core" folder for example.

My question is once the module has become an independent NPM package. How should I handle imports that are referenced inside the module from the app folder that are currently being used?

Thank you